# Intercepting a C++ thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, signals

So I want to be able to handle signals in running threads in C++. I wrote the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <csignal>
using namespace std;

mutex mtx;

void signal_handle(int signal) {
    mtx.lock();
        cout << "Signal intercepted by thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() 
            << endl;
    mtx.unlock();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
}

void thread_func() {
    std::signal(SIGUSR1, signal_handle);

    while(true) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));

        mtx.lock();
            cout << "Thread number looping " << std::this_thread::get_id() << endl;
        mtx.unlock();
    } 
}

void signalling_func() {
    while (true) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
        std::raise(SIGUSR1);
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<thread> threads;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        threads.push_back(thread(thread_func));
    }

    thread(signalling_func).detach();

    for (auto& th : threads) {
        th.join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The signal is never handled by any of the threads I have created. I am assuming it is handled by the main thread. Is there any way I can signal my own threads?

Comment: You can't lock a mutex in a signal handler. Can you be more precise about what you're actually trying to do? There's probably a very good way to do it that might have nothing to do with signals at all.

Comment: I am trying to build a user level thread library. And why can't you lock a mutex in a signal handler? I never knew that

Comment: You can't lock a mutex in a signal handler because mutex functions aren't signal safe. You can only call functions that are guaranteed signal safe in a signal handler. That's why you probably shouldn't use async signal handlers unless you have no choice. You probably do have a choice, but without more details on your use case, it's hard to answer. (Either catch signals synchronously, or only set a volatile boolean to true in the signal handler.)

Comment: Can you explain precisely what you want to do with signals? Most likely, there's some good way to do the very same thing without signals. Signals stick you with lots of behavior that you can't change, whereas if you roll your own solution, you can do it whatever works best for your use case.

Comment: But I can easily make them signal safe in the context of the SIGUSR1 signal by locking a mutex in the signal handler and only signaling when that mutex is released right?

Comment: I am trying to simulate processor interrupts and implement a processor as an OS thread

Comment: No. You can only call async signal safe functions in an async signal handler and the mutex functions aren't signal safe. But if you just don't use async signal handlers, you don't have to worry.

Comment: Oh, okay, now I understand your use case. So, interrupts can only interrupt a processor at defined interruption points. It can't interrupt a processor at arbitrary points such as within instructions. So you need to model the points at which interruption is safe and use some kind of synchronous "were we interrupted" function.

Comment: I am a little confused, sorry. What does signal safe mean? And if I lock a mutex in a signal handler, another thread trying to lock that mutex will have to wait right?

Comment: Async signal safe means the function can be called from an async signal handler. Mutex functions aren't async signal safe, so they can't be called from an async signal handler. My suggestion is just not to use async signal handlers, they have too many restrictions and are too hard to get right. Instead of trying to make something work for your use case, code exactly what your use case requires.

Comment: Yep so that would make the interrupts deterministic though. Unless I use a random seed and not interrupt when the rand() function returns an odd value

Comment: Processor interrupts are deterministic for this very same reason -- it's really, really hard to make asynchronous interruption safe.

Comment: Then good luck. Signals won't help you. You'll have to work out your own way to solve a problem that basically nobody has ever solved.

Comment: And I was under the impression async signal handlers cannot cause interruptions to simple hardware instructions. What did you mean by interrupts within instructions?

Comment: That's correct. The processor only permits interruptions to occur at defined, safe interruption points. If you're trying to emulate processor behavior, you need to do the same thing, also only allowing interruptions at defined, safe interruption points. So when you're at those safe points, you need to check if you've been interrupted, just as the process or does.

Comment: You could have the signal handler set a signal safe boolean to true. Then at safe points, you could check that boolean and handle the interrupt if it's true. That's essentially how the processor handles interrupts, waiting until safe points between instructions to handle them.

Comment: Hmmm interesting. How then can I simulate non determinism? If you know the answer could you write the code in an answer below?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "simulate non determinism". Perhaps you could use some kind of RNG to influence behavior. But you really haven't explained your use case well.

Comment: So you can assume that the thread_func is the CPU running code. I wanted to be able to interrupt that code and run custom code from there on with signalling

Comment: Okay. You don't need signals at all. Use an atomic boolean. Set it to true to interrupt the code. And check if it's true at points where the code can safely be interrupted. That's exactly how processors handle interrupts.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz if I call a function func() in a thread, how do I go about interrupting it with an atomic boolean?

Comment: I described how in the comment you are replying to. To interrupt the code, set it to true. In the interruptible code, check the boolean at points at which the code can safely be interrupted. This is exactly how processors handle interrupts. The interrupt pin sets an internal flag, and between instructions and at other safe points, the processor checks the flag.